# Using grep within while loop

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, grep

I am rather new at this so I imagine I am making a rather simple mistake or possibly going about it in entirely the wrong way.

I am attempting to identify which lines in my first file are present in a list from another file.

File1 is formatted as:

```
FileName1
FileName2
FileName5
FileName6
```

File 2 is formatted as:

```
/dira/FileName1.txt
/dirb/FileName2.txt
/dirc/FileName3.txt
/dird/FileName4.txt
/dire/FileName5.txt
/dirf/FileName6.txt
```

The simple loop I am attempting to run:

```
while read LINE; do grep $LINE listOfFiles2.txt ; done<listOfFiles1.txt
```

The problem:

Nothing is returned. However if I let this complete and check what the last value of LINE was

```
$ echo $LINE
FileName6
```

This makes sense. Also, I can run the command within the loop and receive the expected output.

```
$  grep $LINE listOfFiles2.txt
/dirf/FileName6.txt
```

I think I am missing something but my searches have not given me an answer yet.

Could any of you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it in a single step! `grep -f file_with_patterns file`

Comment: Thanks. I figured I was overthinking this. I am still puzzled why the loop did not work though.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui and anubhava these both explain the problems I was running into. I used the :set ff=unix in vim to fix my original way of trying this as well.

Comment: Your "simple loop" works fine for me.

Comment: Are the real filenames without spaces? `grep My picture of ...listOfFiles2.txt` will try to grep `My` from a lot of files. Not the solution here (that loop will match the first word easy with `File2`), but get used to double quotes around your vars: `"$LINE"` of better `"${line}"` (use lowercase vars and braces)?

Comment: Is your file1 without `\r`. Use `set -x` or try `echo Line=[${line}]"` in the loop.